# FtpWebResponse, the operation timed out

Tags: c#, ftpwebrequest, request-timed-out, ftpwebresponse

I want to download files based on their date time from a ftp server..I can access this Ftp from CuteFtp third party and every thing is Okey..but when I run the code below at line `GetRespone()` I get this error:  the operation has timed out.
I download a sample file from this FTP programmatically with webclient requet and it was fine..but I need to use `FtpWebRequest` to get listDirectoryDetail and webClient does not support that..and one more thing, there is an exception in request: `FtpWebRequest.ContentType` threw an exception of type `System.NotSupportedException`.

here is my code:

```
Uri uri = new Uri("ftp://192.168.1.5:2100/");//the private address
        if (uri.Scheme != Uri.UriSchemeFtp)
        {
            return;
        }
        FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
        reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);                             
        reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myuser", "mypass");
        reqFTP.KeepAlive = false;
        reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails;                               
        reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
        reqFTP.Proxy = null;
        reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
        FtpWebResponse response = (FtpWebResponse)reqFTP.GetResponse();
```

PLEASE HELP :(

Comment: did you check the NetworkCredential username and password? because i guess you copied your code as is.

Comment: of course I've checked it!!..with the wrong user/pass it would get an authentication or login (not sure) error.

Comment: try to change the Uri to map to physical exist file like ""ftp://192.168.1.5:2100/C:/test.txt" and change request method to request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.DownloadFile; and see what you got.

Comment: I did this before..the same error!!!

Comment: try to change the port , set it to the default port 21

Comment: no..the port is important..I think I figured it out...the usepasive property should be true not false!!! because when it is true the client should initiate a connection on the data port..but i cant answer my question until 7 hours later!!!..but I hope this work..thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've Solved my Problem!...the UsePassive property should be set to True, when it is true the client should initiate a connection on the data port

```
reqFTP.UsePassive = true;
```