# C# Windows service times out at FtpWebRequest.GetResponse() in release mode

Tags: c#, .net, ftp, timeout

I've created a simple windows service that checks a FTP folder every 20 seconds and copies any files to the computer locally.

In debug mode it works perfectly, however when I install the release using installutil I catch the following error when calling

```
 using (response = reqFTP.GetResponse())
```

> FTP error...System.Net.WebException: The operation has timed out    at
>   System.Net.FtpWebRequest.SyncRequestCallback(Object obj)    at
>   System.Net.FtpWebRequest.RequestCallback(Object obj)    at
>   System.Net.CommandStream.Dispose(Boolean disposing)    at
>   System.IO.Stream.Close()    at System.IO.Stream.Dispose()    at
>   System.Net.ConnectionPool.Destroy(PooledStream pooledStream)    at
>   System.Net.ConnectionPool.PutConnection(PooledStream pooledStream,
>   Object owningObject, Int32 creationTimeout, Boolean canReuse)    at
>   System.Net.FtpWebRequest.FinishRequestStage(RequestStage stage)    at
>   System.Net.FtpWebRequest.GetResponse()    at
>   FileMan.Service1.GetFileList() in....

The full request is as follows;

```
 string[] downloadFiles;
            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
            WebResponse response = null;
            StreamReader reader = null;
            textWrite.WriteLine("attempting to get file list" + DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine, true);
            try
            {
                FtpWebRequest reqFTP;
                ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit = 100;
                reqFTP = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(downloadSrc));
                reqFTP.UseBinary = true;
                textWrite.WriteLine("requestFTP...Passed..." + DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine, true);
                //reqFTP.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ftpUserID, ftpPassword);
                reqFTP.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory;
                reqFTP.Proxy = null;
                reqFTP.KeepAlive = true;
                reqFTP.UsePassive = false;
                reqFTP.Timeout = 8000;

                //////////STOPS HERE
                //response = reqFTP.GetResponse();
                using (response = reqFTP.GetResponse())
                {
                    // Do stuff
                    //...

                    reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
                    string line = reader.ReadLine();

                    while (line != null)
                    {
                        result.Append(line);
                        result.Append("\n");
                        line = reader.ReadLine();
                    }
                    result.Remove(result.ToString().LastIndexOf('\n'), 1);
                    return result.ToString().Split('\n');
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                textWrite.WriteLine("FTP error..." + ex + "..." + DateTime.Now + Environment.NewLine, true);
                textWrite.Close();
                if (reader != null)
                {
                    reader.Close();
                }
                if (response != null)
                {
                    response.Close();
                }
                downloadFiles = null;
                return downloadFiles;
            }
```

Are there any permissions i need to add?
As this works in debug mode, the code itself is fine. I just needed to figure out what was blocking it

P.S. 
I'm using LocalSystem as the Account and im copying the release build directly to the c drive before installing it using installutil.

Comment: Did your machine connect to the FTP server? Did some firewall block it?

Comment: It had no problem connecting to it in debug mode (running through vs 2015) but times out in release mode Edit: just tried with firewalls off (no luck)

Comment: edrgkjl;rajklsafkjlsfkdaj Just turned of network firewall and it worked.................. Ill add an exception to the firewall and answer this question when i get it stable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FtpWebResponse, the operation timed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17669990/ftpwebresponse-the-operation-timed-out)

Comment: That answer didnt help me

Comment: Well, then you should have stated it in your question, instead of asking the same one again.

Comment: Definitly not a duplicate. SyncRequestCallback timeout was also a firewall thing for me

Answer (score 1):

By turning off public firewall the program worked!
I just added the Service exe to the inbounds firewall rule and it worked Hope this helps anyone else who's having similar troubles